Is it possible to trigger validation on a Minimal API?
I want to generate some endpoints dynamically during app initialization so Minimal APIs are perfect for this. Obviously these are very paired back in terms of functionality and lack the model validation via attributes (e.g [Required]). Is there any way to manually wire up the validation step back into a Minimal API or am I left with things like FluentValidation?

Yeah, just use interception on DI level. No idea how to do this through attributes without losing sanity.


Is it possible to trigger validation on a Minimal API?

Yes you can do that and this can be achieved in may ways. For instance you could manually validate your model inside the minimal API method.
Apart from that, you could use middleware pipeline,also fluent validation also can be used.
For FluentV validation  you would need to install fluent package.
So, its complately depends on your requirement and preference.
Now, let's have a look, how we could implement that using manual validation apporach.
In asp.net core we have validationResult class which used to Initializes a new instance of the ValidationResult class by using an error message and a list of members that have validation errors. So we could use this class.

In order to used above class, we could take the request model using Request.ReadFromJsonAsync and then can use ValidationContext.
Finally, within Validator.TryValidateObject we can pass the model we have received from the request.
Demo Model:
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

Minimal API:
app.MapPost("/modelvalidation", async (HttpContext httpContext) =>
{
    var request = await httpContext.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<MyModel>();

    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(request, null, null);
    bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(request, validationContext, validationResults, true);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        return Results.BadRequest(validationResults);
    }

    return Results.Ok("Model is valid!");
});

Output:



Note: You could refer to this official document for additional reference.
